# Subclipse error when trying to relocate

Tags: svn, subclipse

It says: "attempt to lock an already locked dir".

I do have some changes that is not committed. But I can't commit either as subclipse keep saying: the repository has permanently moved.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Run `svn cleanup` from the command line on the working copy, that should clear the locks.